# Thingsboard-Custom IoT Gateway Connector

Tags: gateway, connector, thingsboard

I'am trying thingsboard's Custom IoT Gateway Connector, The SerialConnector that the gateway already contains this connector. Error reporting during gateway operation，follow:
Connector implementation not found for custom Serial Connector???